# Understanding terraform remote state update and local planning

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform remote state configured on my S3 bucket

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "value"
    key     = "value"
    region  = "value"
    profile = "value"
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "main" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket  = "value"
    key     = value
    region  = "value"
    profile = "value"
  }
}
```

Lets say I want to remove a module from the terraform to track in my planning, for example `module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0]`

I can use: `terraform state rm module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0]`, and this will hypothetically remove the module's json code block in the remote state file.

Now let's presume I try another method, go directly to the remote json state file and delete the following json block:

```
{
      "module": "module.eks",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "kubernetes_config_map",
      "name": "aws_auth",
      "each": "list",
      "provider": "provider.kubernetes",
      "instances": [
.....
```

Then, running terraform plan doesn't do any changes! I should see add new `module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0]`, or if I delete the tf code block of the module - no changes. How? the remote module block was deleted, but seems to me, locally I still have the old state.

Looking at the terraform plan output, before it starts it does some kind of refreshing of in-memory state:

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

module.bastion.null_resource.tags_as_list_of_maps[0]: Refreshing state... [id=##########]
module.bastion.data.template_file.user_data: Refreshing state...
data.terraform_remote_state.main: Refreshing state...
module.eks.aws_iam_role.cluster[0]: Refreshing state...
...
```

but local terrafrom.tfstate shows:

```
"version": 3,
    "serial": 5,
    "lineage": "######",
    "backend": {
        "type": "s3",
        "config": {
            "access_key": #####,
.....
```

Does anyone has an idea of how local planning work with the remote state? does it look directly to the remote state file when running terraform plan?

Comment: Unless you remove the code from the tf files, Terraform tries to recreate it. So, if doing things manually, delete the code and the entry in the state.

Comment: I tried that, "running terraform plan doesn't do any changes! I should see add new module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0]" since tf would try to re-create it but it shows me no changes